# Denying unauthorized users from editing a profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to setup so that users will get a "not authorized" message if they click edit for a profile that is not theirs. This message should of course not appear for admins since admins can edit all profiles. I previously done this on Permission.rb, however I got rid of the file to go with a more basic user roles/authorization.

I don't see how I can implement what I had previously on Permission.rb for my current files. I have tried some solutions but they don't add up. If someone could point me in the right direction that will be great. Also I am doing this all from scratch, user authentication/authorization.

index.html.erb:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li>
        <% if current_user.admin? || current_user == @user %>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to "Edit #{user} profile", user %>

            | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                          data: { confirm: "You sure?"} %>
        </li>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: Sorry thought I did that this morning, but it was for another question. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: look at my edit at the end of the answer. You were putting your `<% end %>` too soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you giving the chance for users to edit other peoples profiles?

First, you should have a `if` statement in your view where you show the link for the edit page. I guess this is showing up on a profile of every user, so i suppose the code in your controller is something like this:

```
def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Then in your view you should have something like this:

```
<% if current_user.admin? || current_user == @user %>
   <%= link_to 'Edit Profile' , edit_user_path(@user) %>
<% end %>
```

There is also a case if someone tries to 'force' their way in, just like trying to type a url `www.yourapplication.com/users/6/edit` you could write a `before_filter` method in your controller:

```
before_filter :check_privileges, only => [:edit, :update]
```

and then write a method in called `check_privileges`

```
def check_privileges
  unless current_user.admin? || current_user.id == params[:id]
     flash[:warning] = 'not authorized!'
     redirect_to root_path 
  end
end
```

EDIT: After the questioner edited his code, i'm showing the mistake:

You are putting the `end` too soon:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li>
        <%= link_to user.name, user %>
        <% if current_user.admin? || current_user == @user %>
            <%= link_to "Edit #{user} profile", user %>
            | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                          data: { confirm: "You sure?"} %>
        <% end %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: On top of that I recommend to take a look on this online book, more specifically this section: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec-authorization

Comment: I didn't add the privileges part yet. But your first solution only seem to block people from viewing the /users page if they're not logged in. If a user has login, he can still edit profiles even if it's someone else's. The way I have the pages setup now is you go to /users and it list all the registered users. On that page you click username, and it'll take you to /users/ID where you can view/edit profile (I haven't created a template yet that outputs the profile information only). So instead what it should do is not allow anyone who is not the owner to view/edit the profile.

Comment: "If a user has login, he can still edit profiles even if it's someone else's". What?

Comment: But your first solution only seem to block people from viewing the /users page if they're not logged in => don't put the entire view in the if statement, just the part about editing. If you have your edit and view are on the same page then you should just hide the form with that if statement and thats it.

Comment: What I meant was if User A logged in to their account, User A should not be able to view/edit User B profile. That is the issue I have been having. User A can still view User B profile. Only admin should be able to view all profiles, and if you're a normal "user" you should be restricted to only your own profile.

Comment: Then include the `:show` action in the before_filter method also.